# Reading path to double clicked file on Mac

Tags: javafx

I am making a simple MP3 Tag editor using JavaFx for my own use on my Mac

I can right click an MP3 file and view the info with Get Info and set the association for MP3s to be my tag editor when the file is double clicked

A command line version of the app would accept the path/filename through the String args passed on the command line but with a JavaFx application this is not passed.

So I was wondering, how do I get the path to the file that launched the JavaFx app?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want to double-click on a file, this should open your JavaFX application, and you then want to find out which file your application has been opened for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not help you much but there is a bug report asking for exactly this.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187992

Comment: Thanks this was useful as the bug provides some source code which gave me an example of what i was looking for in setFXFileHandler()

Comment: Glad to hear that. There is also a discussion on SO concerning this topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569389/missing-openfilesevent-for-javafx-on-mac/46457669#46457669